# Error microsoft Blend for visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, blend

I have just installed Visual Studio ultimate on windows 7 (32bit) , i'm trying to open Blend but it keeps telling me that there is an error:

[image]

in english :Blend for visual studio supports only windows store app development on windows 8. to develop windows presentation foundation(WPF) or silverlight applications , install Blend + SketchFlow for Visual Studio 2012."

Have you got any ideas about the ways i could solve this problem with? , thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you try openning Blend directly with a project, I guess you have to use the link it's gave to you and try Blend + sketchflow.
Blend for VS 2012 works for Windows 8 and you are on windows 7, maybe it's the problem.

Sorry if I don't help, I can't just comment right now.